# Cassandra warning about CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-python-driver

When I run my Python scripts that use Cassandra, I get the following warning:

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py:545: UserWarning: CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT environment variable is not set. Future versions of this package will require this variable to enable management functions.
```

Sounds reasonable enough, but I searched and I searched and couldn't figure out what `CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT` is or how to set it.

What is it and what should I set it to?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [code of the driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py), it seems that it is a boolean flag that will indicate if the application will be allowed or not to modify the schema with the application.

There are several examples like this fix for [a django project](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine/commit/0d662485983f30cfce4d80be72365e7e0f29f968) or this [eventsourcing code](https://eventsourcing.readthedocs.io/en/v6.0.0/_modules/eventsourcing/infrastructure/cassandra/datastore.html) that solves the issue with a *quick and dirty* approach, setting explicitly the value with something like:

```
if os.getenv('CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT') is None:
    os.environ['CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT'] = '1'
```

Doing some additional research, [Srikanth Bemineni's post in the driver forum](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/python-driver-user/2dCzDFIYYiw), mentioned that he was able to solve the issue using the *new integrated cqlengine in the cassandra python driver* instead of using the cqlengine from the module, but I couldn't figure out what was he referring to.